# Blender 3.6 Baking Displacement From Multires Not Working

Tags: texture-baking, displacement, multiresolution

I created a cylinder, applied a multires modifier, subdivided 5 times, and did some sculpting. Back in object mode i turned Viewport Levels to 0, turned on Cycles with GPU Compute, added a material and inside the material an empty (non-color) image texture which I selected before I pressed Bake -> From Multires -> Displacement. But the image turns out white/slightly gray with no details on it. Baking normals works fine.

Blender file below.

[image]

I literally can't make it work:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided Blender file, I tried the following:
Doing the same process as described in the question on a new Mesh (Round Cube) added to the same file. Baking displacement on this new mesh works fine, so I suspected something was wrong with my original (cylinder) mesh. I switched into Edit Mode and cleared all sharp edges + set all creases back to 0. Now it works and I have no clue why. And I also don't understand why it worked for @moonboots.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, make sure that your image is *32-Bit Float*, and that you plug your *Image Texture* node into the *Height* input of a *Bump* node (that you plug into the *Normal* input of your *Principled BSDF*).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it still does not work. I updated my question with a screenshot. I am not sure if I have to connect my image node to a shader while baking? But no matter how I do it (connected or not). I get a blank image.

Comment: Maybe try with another Blender version?